# How to get the base url on javascript?

Tags: javascript, url

I have a page that is available on address below
`http://localhost/foo/test/index.html`
and
`http://localhost/foo/test`
(without back slash)

I can place a css file in the parent directory (`http://localhost/foo/test/style.css`) and add it on the page with

```html
<link rel = "stylesheet" href = "../style.css" />
```

and browser will successfully load the style sheet.

If we look at `window.location`, it's `http://localhost/foo/test/index.html` on the first reference and `http://localhost/foo/test` on the second reference (i.e. we have an additional path element in the end of the first url and don't have it in the second one).

How does a browser know, that he should make a request to `http://localhost/foo/style.css` to get style sheet content in both cases?
And how can I get this base url with client-side javascript (or know that `test` is a directory and not a file)?
For example if I want to know that requests to `http://localhost/foo/style.css` and `../style.css` are the same.

Notice: I can't use server side code for it.

**UPD**: There is an error in the question. Browser doesn't correctly load the style sheet from url without a slash on the end. Thank you!

Comment: Use a path starting from the root. `/foo/style.css`.

Comment: @Reyno the question is not about this specific case.

Answer (score 0):

Not a full answer for sure but on JS side try window.location object

`window.location.href` returns the href (URL) of the current page

`window.location.hostname` returns the domain name of the web host

`window.location.pathname` returns the path and filename of the current page

`window.location.protocol` returns the web protocol used (http: or https:)

`window.location.assign()` loads a new document

source: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_window_location.asp

Comment: Yes, I read about it. But it returns the url from browser's address bar. Not the current page url.

Comment: the current page and the URL from the browser's address bar are the same, isn't it?

Comment: If we get the same page from http://localhost/foo/test/index.html and from http://localhost/foo/test, window.location is different
(I've found an error in my question and updated it. Thank you!)

Answer (score 0):

You can get base URL of current site by using JavaScript window Object

```js
console.log(window.location.origin)
//gives the current url
```